# Conditional Convergence Property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How would one prove or disprove (provide a counterexample) the statement

$$\text{If}\ \sum a_n\ \text{converges conditionally, then }\sum n^2 a_n\ \text{diverges}. $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: if $\sum n^2 a_n$ converges,  its terms are bounded.